# A question on laplace transform

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace, laplace-method

I try to solve the following question on Laplace transform

$$L(\{ \int_0^{t}e^{-x^2}\})$$

I solved as following:
$$L(\{ \int_0^{t}e^{-x^2}\})=\frac{1}{s}L(\{e^{-x^2}\})=\frac{1}{s}L(\{\sum_0^{\infty}\frac{(-t)^{2n}}{n!}\})$$
So
$$\sum_0^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(2n)!}{n!s^{2n+2}}.$$

Can you suggest another way to solve this Laplace transform?

Comment: [This](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Laplace_Transform_of_Error_Function) might give you some ideas

Comment: Thank you Victor!

Comment: @Moo Yep, I know it.

Comment: If anything, the answer is $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } e^{\frac{s^2}{4}} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=LaplaceTransform%5B+Exp%5B-t%5E2%5D%2C+t%2C+s%5D

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with the Laplace transform of $e^{-x^2}$:

$$ \mathcal{L}(e^{-x^2})(t) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2-xt}\,dx =e^{t^2/4}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-(x+t/2)^2}\,dx = e^{t^2/4}\int_{t/2}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx.$$
The Laplace transform of $\int_{0}^{x}e^{-u^2}\,du$ is easily related to the previous one:

$$ \mathcal{L}\left(\int_{0}^{x}e^{-u^2}\,du\right)(t) = \frac{e^{t^2/4}}{\color{red}{t}}\int_{t/2}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx. $$